# Difference between 'foreach' and 'parallel' in R?

Tags: r, parallel-foreach, rparallel

As the title suggest, I am confused about what is the difference between both package as they are both used in parallel computing in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach` can execute using either `%do%` or `%dopar%` ... it only runs in parallel with `%dopar%`

More information available here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf

Comment: how about 'parallel' or 'doParallel' package?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf